# Calculation of transmission loss of a power plant

Tags: power-supply, resistance, transmission-line, loss

What is the transmission loss due to heat if my power station produces electricity at a power of \$5 kW\$ and the electricity consumer is \$1 km\$ away?

It is a copper line with a material constant of \$0.017\Omega \frac{mm^2}{m}\$, a voltage of \$1kV\$ and a cross-section of \$10mm^2\$.

My approach, which I don't know if it's true or not, is as follows:
$$I_{cable} = \frac{P_{generated}}{U_{grid}} = \frac{5kW}{1kV} = 5A$$
$$R_{cable} = \rho * \frac{l}{A} = 0.017\Omega \frac{mm^2}{m} * \frac{1000m}{10mm^2} = 1.7\Omega$$
$$P_{loss} = (I_{cable}^2R_{cable})* 2 = 85W$$ 
So that of the \$5000W\$ produced about \$5000W - 85W = 4915W\$ can be consumed.

Is the calculation so possible? If not, then how?

Comment: for a first contribution, using equation markup like a pro, excellent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your engineering is correct, the power loss in the cable is \$I^2R\$.

This calculation is a good demonstration for why nationwide power distribution needs transmission voltages in the 100s of kV, and even a district tends to use 10s of kV, to control the power loss in the distribution cables to be reasonable, or avoid unaffordable conductors with the cross section of tree trunks.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed and informative answer.
In my calculation I have calculated the loss for the outward and return route of the current (\$(I_{cable}^2R_{cable})* 2\$), so that the loss of the cable is doubled. Does the return path also have to be considered?

Comment: @AnneBierhoff You have allowed for the return path correctly. Personally, I would have calculated the total loop resistance as 3.4ohms, and not doubled the power calculation, but that's just a matter of style, **if** it is indeed a loop of two similar wires for out and return, which it usually is. If the 'return' is for some reason a different conductor type to the 'out', like around a car for instance, that's when calculating the total resistance is the tidier way to do the sums.